# How can a black hole grow, as seen by an outside observer?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

How can a black hole grow in mass, if it takes an infinite time to cross the event horizon,  for matter approaching the black hole (as seen from an outside observer far from the black hole)?

To make a black hole, one must concentrate mass or energy sufficiently that the escape velocity from the region in which it is concentrated exceeds the speed of light.

So , as seen from an outside observer, we have redshift and time dilation (all the GR effects in action ) for matter approaching the event horizon of a black hole.

Eventually (in finite time ),  the outside observer sees sufficient matter (energy ) accumulating in a small neighborhood of the event horizon of the original  black hole that other  black holes must emerge (in the neighborhood of the event horizon of the original black hole ). So the outside observer sees a continuous merging of black holes , those formed in the neighborhood of the event horizon of the original black hole, and the original black hole itself. That could explain how a black hole can grow, even as seen from an outside observer.

Question.  Is this explanation correct?

Comment: Many duplicates.

Comment: I know, but I want to clarify the process, as seen from outside.  Nowhere in the related questions this process is explained in detail. I mean the black hole mergers.

Comment: Yes, @RobJeffries that answers my question,. Didn't see it. Thank you.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: [Does an expanding event horizon “swallow” nearby objects?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/415484/does-an-expanding-event-horizon-swallow-nearby-objects)

Comment: Thank you @JohnRennie

Comment: Then again, for a distant observer, an event horizon takes infinite time to form. I'm back to square one. I'll look into  the math. Anyway, thank you @JohnRennie