# Images on the event horizon of a black hole as the black hole grows

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

My layperson's understanding is that when an object falls into a black hole, outside observers see a progressively-redshifted image of the object at the event horizon. What happens to that image as the horizon grows? Does the image move outward with the horizon, does it disappear behind it, or does something else happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does an expanding event horizon "swallow" nearby objects?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/415484/does-an-expanding-event-horizon-swallow-nearby-objects) Note that the highest voted answer to that question is not the currently accepted answer.

Comment: Bear in mind that any image from the vicinity of the event horizon becomes dim very quickly, and it's massively red-shifted. And that also applies to an infalling object that is itself a light source.