# When does the event horizon grow as measured by a distant observer?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

As measured by a far away observer, it takes an infinite amount of time for a body to fall into a black hole (though the body itself takes finite time to reach the crunch). The event horizon grows only after mass is added to a black hole, which essentially means it grows after after inifinity. Does that mean the horizon can never grow as measured by a remote observer? But that cannot be true, can it - we can directly take photos of the accretion disk, which should grow larger if the horizon grows.

So when does the horizon grow, as measured by a distant observer?

Related question (not yet answered):
[When does a black hole grow?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/677362/when-does-a-black-hole-grow?noredirect=1#comment1517739_677362)

Comment: I can't see how the question you linked differs from this one.

Comment: Not much different. It just clarifies details. You can answer either one.

Comment: Hi Nayeem1. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.